# How to convert .caf to .mp3 file programmatically on the iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, mp3

is there a way to programmatically convert .caf audio files to .mp3 audio files on the iPad platform?

Comment: Can you do this server-side instead or does it have to be on the device?

Comment: It has to be on the device because it is a local app

Answer (score 3):

There is NO way to encode TO mp3 on the iPhone.  Apple does not provide the encoders for mp3, presumably due to licensing.

Answer (score 0):

```
OSStatus AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(

   AudioConverterRef                   inAudioConverter,      
   AudioConverterComplexInputDataProc  inInputDataProc,   
   void                                *inInputDataProcUserData,   
   UInt32                              *ioOutputDataPacketSize,  
   AudioBufferList                     *outOutputData,  
   AudioStreamPacketDescription        *outPacketDescription  
);
```

Still working on an implementation, but this method is meant to be used for this conversion.

It is declared in `audiotoolbox -> audioConverter`

Comment: any luck ? I was looking for a caf to mp3 converter too !!

Comment: I am also looking for it. Did you succeed with this?? or using any other library or API??

Comment: Did you ever get this working?