# iOS: Create an MP3 on device

Tags: iphone, audio, ios, mp3

I am trying to create an MP3 audio file on the device (iPhone).

I have found that there is no possibility to record directly in MP3 format.
Only .caf file that may contain AIFF, Linear PCM etc.

I have also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474547/how-to-convert-caf-to-mp3-file-programmatically-on-the-iphone-or-ipad) that there is an `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` function that might, theoretically, convert CAF file to MP3, but I can't find any sample code or explanation on how to use this function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

--
Michael Kessler

Comment: If there's no existing libraries that do it, maybe it's time someone wrote one! ;)

Comment: There is an API for this (`AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer`), but I don't understand how to work with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LAME - open source MP3 encoder library (liblame)

http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if it will work on iOS? Have you tried this library?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know LAME is GPL which may be an issue for you if you are building an iPhone app.

I believe AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer indeed is the way to go. You might want to take a look at the book "Core Audio Rough Cuts" which has explanations and examples on how to convert audio.

Good luck.