# AudioStreamBasicDescription for mp3

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audioqueue

I have an Audio Queue working to record PCM, but I cannot get it to work for mp3. When I change the mFormatID to kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3, my callback function is never fired. I am using the example from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mp3 encoder is not bundled in iOS as far as I know as it's a patented algorithm. You can only decode (playback) mp3 audio.

Consider using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or some other encoder on the server side to transform the audio to mp3.

Or get [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) (mp3 encoder) as listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145623/ios-create-an-mp3-on-device).

Answer (score 1):

Anurag is right: Core Audio won't encode MP3. Your approach will work for other CA-supported compressed codecs, like AAC and ALAC.